# How can I stop the kafka container?

Tags: docker, containers

I setup my kafka containers by follow the tutorial from here: https://success.docker.com/article/getting-started-with-kafka

Then I found that I can't remove the container anymore, even though I tried docker container prune. The containers are still running.

What should I do?

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                          NAMES
caa0b94c1d98        qnib/plain-kafka:1.1.0                    "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes (healthy)                                  broker.2.3fij6pt90qt9sb9aco0i2dpys
b888cb6f783a        qnib/plain-kafka:1.1.0                    "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes (healthy)                                  broker.3.xqmjnfnfg7ha46lf6drlrq4ki
dcdda2d778c2        qnib/plain-kafka:1.1.0                    "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes (healthy)                                  broker.1.gtgluxt6q58z2irzgfmu969ba
843def0b24fb        qnib/plain-zkui                           "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes (healthy)                                  zkui.1.7zks618eae8sp4woc7araydix
d7ced19be88c        qnib/plain-kafka-manager:2018-04-25       "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes (healthy)                                  manager.1.jdu5gnprhr4d982vz50511rhg
a67ac962e682        qnib/plain-zookeeper:2018-04-25           "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes (healthy)   2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp   zookeeper.1.xar7cmdgozdj79orow0bmj3ev
880121f2fee5        qnib/golang-kafka-producer:2018-05-01.5   "kafka-producer"         3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes (healthy)                                  producer.2.hety8za590v1twdgj2byvrmse
b6487d29812e        qnib/golang-kafka-producer:2018-05-01.5   "kafka-producer"         3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes (healthy)                                  producer.1.5oz02c8cw5oefc97xbarq5qoa
8b3a81905e90        qnib/golang-kafka-producer:2018-05-01.5   "kafka-producer"         3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes (healthy)                                  producer.3.p8uh3hzr22fgm7u4gl1p3fiyw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I have to use `docker service rm` to remove the service due to the `replicas` settings.

Answer (score 0):

The prune command doesn't work against running containers.  You will need to either stop or kill them.

```
docker kill caa0b94c1d98
```